# Store image as blob in firebird

Tags: database, firebird

I want to store image data inside database as blob. Database is firebird. On adding new field of type blob I have SegmentSize = 16384 and SubType.

I was thinking to leave SegmentSize as is and to use SubType as value 0 which represents binary data. Is this ok?

Comment: I would not even worry about SegmentSize.  It doesn't sound like it does anything database side -- it's [information for the client](https://www.mail-archive.com/firebird-support@yahoogroups.com/msg01229.html) to smartly request chunks of the data at a time back when memory was severely limited.

Comment: And yes, sub type 0 will work.  For one project I store email attachments (PDFs) this way!  Segment size is defaulted to 80.

Comment: @nater It actually does, or at least, blobs are stored as segments, but I think (not 100% sure) existing Firebird versions store segments in the size they were received from the client, not in the configured segment size. The segment size is more a hint to the client these days (as in: retrieve it in blocks of 'segment size').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This technique has worked well for me. Segment size should be somewhere between 80 and 65536, with 2048 as a recommended standard.

Comment: Maximum segment size depends on the Firebird version, older version (1.x, maybe 2.0) are limited to 32767. As segments introduce some storage overhead, bigger might be better.